# Error "The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present. Continue to wait" after 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, boot, mount, tmp

I updated to 16.04 from 14.04 and now i have this error, i have searched on the internet and for some people doing:

```
sudo mv /tmp /tmp_old
sudo mkdir /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

but it didn´t for me

This is my fstab file after i pressed M for manual mount:
[fstab file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gsp5.jpg)

And this is the output of blkid
[blkid output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdVUH.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, i added it on the first link, but it is this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gsp5.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  You need to comment out the `/dev/vg00/lv_tmp` from your `/etc/fstab` file by adding a `#` in the front of that line so that it doesn't load at startup.

Comment: After doing it i get  almost the same error but now for usr and if comment all those lines (tmp, usr, var and localdata) i get to this screen: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOuoYpEtBPLfY23EsTKQLtJC7YZTdGCZToVOYvzHJ3KQXMsDv5b4CR8i7Kuo7a88A/photo/AF1QipOt6kboiIho8Rjgo5VkGKKeAxt1_wFsnzffl7lH?key=YS1fNjFiN0pCVkc3djFwalJacl9tMlYyZTVuWXVn

Comment: If i try to log on previous kernel, i am able to do it but no network in there, does that help for troubleshooting?

Comment: I did it but then i get almost same error: Error “The disk drive for /usr is not ready yet or not present. Continue to wait... So i tried commenting it also  but in the end i got stuck on the screen i posted before

Comment: Looks like the LVM names then might have changed.  I am looking for possible answers for this.  I have used LVM in the past, but I am not a fan of it due to it's complexity.  Maybe someone might come along and know exactly what you need to do so that you can get the mounts back up.

Comment: Look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/596835/i-need-help-mounting-an-lvm2-partition-with-14-04-lts-live-usb as it might help and contain something that might help you.  You might have to change the mount lines in your fstab if the `vg` name is different than `vg00`.

Comment: Thanks, i tried with  "vgchange -a y vg00" and i was able to mount /tmp and /usr and /var after that i tried "dpkg --configure -a" as advised on some posts and i got this error: https://goo.gl/wAaNMx

Comment: Maybe i should create another post because this is moving in other direction

Comment: You could.  Probably recommended.  Put in as much detail as you can and try to avoid screenshots.  See if you can copy and paste the text.  If you can't, that's understandable.  But more details the more it will help.